# Why does ring contraction take place in Wagner–Meerwein rearrangement?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation, rearrangements

An example of Wagner–Meerwein rearrangement given in my textbook is substitution by $\ce{AgNO2}$ in iodocyclohexane. One of the product, cyclopentylnitromethane is through ring contraction.

I don't understand how this took place. Can anyone explain the mechanism?

Comment: It would be a mistake to think that a five-member ring is very strained.

Comment: I know it isn't 'very strained'. I am editing the question. The main question is how is the rearrangement happening.

Comment: This reference from 1952 claims that the product of the reaction is nitrocyclohexane. No rearrangement. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01132a037. A previous study had claimed additionally the formation of 1-methylnitrocyclopentane, which is not cyclopentylnitromethane. What is the name of your textbook?

Comment: @user55119, S.N.Sanyal - Reactions, Rearrangements and Reagents ; Publisher: Bharti Bhawan ; Page-185. You may find this book online. Also, in your link, it is clearly mentioned that Rosanow discovered rearranged products in 1915, i.e. **Wagner-Meerwin Rearrangement is happening**

Comment: Kornblum was unable to confirm Rosanow's observation of the tertiary nitro compound (see last paragraph in the text). Assuming that there is some rearrangement, how would 1-methylnitrocyclopentane be formed rather than cyclopentylnitromethane as your text claims?

Comment: I'll post a solution.

Comment: I would think the product mixture depends on conditions.

Comment: Methods of structural analysis have changed considerably since 1915. I think it unwise to accept uncritically the suggestion of the formation of cyclopentylnitromethane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kornblum<sup>[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01132a037)</sup> demonstrated that nitrocyclohexane **3** was the major isolable product from the reaction of iodocyclohexane **1** and silver nitrite. Earlier work by Rosanow<sup>2</sup> (1915) claimed the additional formation of tertiary nitro compound **7**, a result that Kornblum did not confirm. If indeed nitrocyclopentane **7** did form, a ring contraction is required. Ring contraction of cyclohexyl carbocation **2** sacrifices the greater stability of a secondary carbocation for a primary carbocation (**4**) and presumably some loss in stability through ring contraction in forming cyclopentyl carbocation **6**. There is no evidence that primary nitrocyclopentane **5** is formed. However, a hydride shift in **4** would afford the more stable tertiary carbocation **6** that would lead to **7**.

[image]
1) N. Kornblum and C. Teitelbaum, [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1952**, *71*, 3076.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01132a037)
2) See reference in Kornblum paper.

Comment: Structure 5 is given in my textbook as one of the products.

Comment: Structure 5 is not present in the Kornblum paper. There maybe a problem in interpreting the names of 5 and 7. OTOH, some information in textbooks is gleaned from memory.